# Broadcasting an OP_RETURN transaction

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, php, op-return

I am facing two problems below,

First is that I am trying to broadcast transaction which have OP_RETURN but blockchain.info continuously rejecting it, though I have broadcast it using bitcoind.

Second is that what is the best way to insert an OP_RETURN data into the raw transaction. Currently I am following this method ---> [What is a step by step way to insert data in OP_RETURN?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/what-is-a-step-by-step-way-to-insert-data-in-op-return/36439#36439)

but i know this is not a standard way.

I am using php and bitcoind server!

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Blockchain.info doesn't know how to understand OP_RETURN outputs. Just because one website isn't showing it doesn't mean it hasn't made it around the network.

Comment: I'm the guy who wrote the answer that you're linking to. I'm having trouble understanding your second question. Are you asking if it's still a good method?

Comment: @Bitcoin I think he means that blockchain.info/pushtx didn't work.

Comment: @NickODell Same response really, blockchain.info doesn't understand OP_RETURN transactions and won't relay them through that interface as a result.

Comment: @Bitcoin Oh, that might be it also.

Comment: @NickODell Yup I know you wrote the answer, And yes I was asking that if it's a good method or not?. And is there any alternative to that method ?

Comment: @NickODell ????

Answer (score 2):

blockchain.info's pushtx feature will reject transactions with OP_RETURN in it.

You might want to try my tool https://github.com/kaykurokawa/pushtx

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain.info does not display transactions with OP_RETURNs until they are confirmed on the blockchain.

You can view all recent OP_RETURN transactions on [Coin Secrets](http://coinsecrets.org/), and there's a link from there to a simple PHP library for working with OP_RETURNs.